# How to convert a Dockerfile to a docker compose image?

Tags: node.js, meteor, docker, docker-compose

This is how I'm creating a docker image with nodeJS and meteorJS based on an ubuntu image. I'll use this image to do some testing.

Now I'm thinking of doing this via docker compose. But is this possible at all? Can I convert those commands into a docker compose yml file?

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY package.json ./

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -yqq \
        python \
        build-essential \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        locales \
        nodejs \
        npm \
        nodejs-legacy \
        sudo \
        git

## NodeJS and MeteorJS
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh

## Dependencies
RUN npm install -g eslint eslint-plugin-react
RUN npm install

## Locale
ENV OS_LOCALE="en_US.UTF-8"
RUN locale-gen ${OS_LOCALE}
ENV LANG=${OS_LOCALE} LANGUAGE=en_US:en LC_ALL=${OS_LOCALE}

## User
RUN useradd ubuntu && \
    usermod -aG sudo ubuntu && \
    mkdir -p /builds/core/.meteor /home/ubuntu && \
    chown -Rh ubuntu:ubuntu /builds/core/.meteor && \
    chown -Rh ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu
USER ubuntu
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Docker Compose doesn't replace your Dockerfile, but you can use Docker Compose to [build an image from your Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build):

```
version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: /path/to/Dockerfile/dir
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: result/latest
```

Now you can build it with:

```
docker-compose build
```

And start it with:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: How do I set the name and label of the created image/container to get something like `result:latest`?

Comment: To build an image docker compose is not required. You should use [docker build command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/). Docker compose is used to create multiple services and make sure that they can talk to each other, like an infrastructure setup where you need web app, db, elastich search (let's say) and redis (let's say)

Comment: @ArtūrsLataks, I agree, `docker build` is the normal way to build an image, but there are times when you may want to build with docker compose, for example when running autotests (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-continuous-integration-testing-environment-with-docker-and-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: @user3142695, you can use the `image` key in conjunction with the `build` key to tag the built image: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image See updated answer above.

Comment: @Brian yes, that is what I said - when you need multiple services that are interacting between themselves :)